# Convert a list of POJO to a Map<String,Set<String>>

Tags: java, collections

I have a `List<POJO>` in which each POJO has a field "ID" which has a value "IP_ADDRESS". I want to aggregate this List to a `Map<ID,Set<IP_ADDRESS>>`.

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> listToMapConverters(List<NormalizedSyslogMessage> listOfNormalizedSyslogMessages) {
        Map<String, Set<String>> partyToHostNameMapping = new HashMap<>();
        for (NormalizedSyslogMessage message : listOfNormalizedSyslogMessages) {
            Set<String> hostIpSet = new TreeSet<>();
            hostIpSet.add(message.getIpaddress().toString());
            partyToHostNameMapping.put(message.getPartyID().toString(),
                    hostIpSet);
        }
    }
```

I am getting set of individual ipaddresses as sets for each id where i want to aggregate the IpAddresses for a specific ID.

I do not want to use any third party libraries because of project constraints. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: can you please share the input data how it is look like.

Comment: Pojo a = new Pojo();
  a.setId(1);
  List aList=new ArrayList();  
  aList.add("100.255.255.254");
  aList.add("100.255.255.254");//duplicate Ipaddress
  aList.add("101.255.255.254");
  aList.add("102.255.255.254");

Comment: Can you share the code for the `POJO` (`NormalizedSyslogMessage` ?) class?

Answer (score 2):

Rather than creating a new `TreeSet` in each iteration of the for loop, you need to check if the appropriate entry value already exists in the map `partyToHostnameMapping` and add the `IP_ADDRESS` to that one instead, if it exists.

Answer (score 0):

You may want to check if this ID key already exists.

If it doesn't, add it as you where already doing.

If it does, just add the IP address to the existing `Set` .

```
   for (NormalizedSyslogMessage message : listOfNormalizedSyslogMessages) {

        Set<String> existingSet = partyToHostNameMapping.get(message.getPartyID().toString());

        if(existingSet == null){

            Set<String> hostIpSet = new TreeSet<>();
            hostIpSet.add(message.getIpaddress().toString());
            partyToHostNameMapping.put(message.getPartyID().toString(),
                hostIpSet);

        }
        else{

            existingSet.add(message.getIpaddress().toString());
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Java 8 features like streams and lambda:

```
 Map<ID, Set<IP_ADDRESS>> someMap=
            List.stream().collect(groupingBy(POJO::getId, mapping(POJO::getIP_ADDRESS, toSet()));
```

Answer (score -1):

You need to reuse the `Set` in the `Map` if it's already present.

```
public Map<String, Set<String>> listToMapConverters(List<NormalizedSyslogMessage> listOfNormalizedSyslogMessages) {
    Map<String, Set<String>> partyToHostNameMapping = new HashMap<>();
    for (NormalizedSyslogMessage message : listOfNormalizedSyslogMessages) {
        // create Set only if not present already
        Set<String> hostIpSet = partyToHostNameMapping.computeIfAbsent(message.getPartyID().toString(), k -> new TreeSet<>());
        hostIpSet.add(message.getIpaddress().toString());
    }
}
```